# Magento 2 - Create new order number after updating an order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, sales, edit, create

Create new order number after updating an order.

When order `0000123` was edited, magento created order `0000138` instead of `0000123-1`

Answer (score 0):

That's an default Magento behaviour. To read more related to this please visit below link : https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-update.html

[image]

And if you still wish to continue modifying details without creating new order, do visit Magento Marketplace store or google 'Magento edit order' and you'll find many extensions fulfilling your requirement or you can build on yourself.